# Problemas a editar items dentro da struct

Tags: c, array, struct

tenho a seguinte struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    char nome[50];
    int tipoUser;
    float vencimentos;
    int id_clinica;

} Utilizador;
```

insiro na mesma valores a partir das seguintes funções :

```
void criarUser(Utilizador *utilizador, int n)
{

    printf("NOME: ");
    fgets(utilizador->nome, 50, stdin);
    utilizador->nome[strcspn(utilizador->nome, "\n")] = 0;

    printf("Vencimentos: ");
    scanf("%f", &utilizador->vencimentos);

    printf("tipo de user(1-Medico,2-Enfermeiro,3-Funcionario) ");
    scanf("%d", &utilizador->tipoUser);
    utilizador->id = n + 1;
    printf("id da clinica a que está associada ");
    scanf("%d", &utilizador->id_clinica);
}
boolean inserirUser(Utilizador *utilizadores, int *n, Utilizador utilizador)
{
    if (*n > TAMUtilizador)
    {
        return false;
    }

    utilizadores[*n] = utilizador;
    (*n)++;

    return true;
}
```

queria agora editar  os valores dentro da struct e gostaria de saber o porque de não estar a funcionar
calls as functions:

```
 id_edicao=editarUser(utilizadores,&nUsers);
        criarComIdUser(utilizadores, id_edicao);
```

functions:

```
int editarUser(Utilizador *utilizadores, int *n)
{
    listarUsers(utilizadores, *n);
    int idAlterar;
    printf("Qual o id que quer alterar?");
    scanf("%d", &idAlterar);
    return idAlterar;
}
void criarComIdUser(Utilizador *utilizadores, int n)
{
  
    
   
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (i == n)
        {
            float vencimento;
            int tipoUser;
            int id_clinica;
            printf("%d",n);
            printf("Vencimentos: ");
            scanf("%f",&vencimento);

            printf("tipo de user(1-Medico,2-Enfermeiro,3-Funcionario) ");
            scanf("%d", &tipoUser);
             
            printf("id da clinica a que está associada ");
            scanf("%d",&id_clinica);
           
            utilizadores[n].id_clinica=id_clinica;
            utilizadores[n].tipoUser=tipoUser;
            utilizadores[n].vencimentos=vencimento;

            
        }

    }
}
```

não retorna nenhum erro, simplesmente não edita os valores, o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se eu observei bem, esta passando um ponteiro como valor, e precisa passar a posição de memoŕia da estrutura. Veja se não é isso, como segue um exemplo explicativo a baixo.

Se quiser testar o codigo use o:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler

Tem a opção de debugger, mesmo não substituindo uma compilação local, é uma mão na roda, veja se isso resolve.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    float z;
} USER;

/* Recebe um ponteiro */
int insert_user( USER *ext_user )
  {
  if(ext_user == NULL)
    {
    free(ext_user);
    return -1;
    }

  printf("Insercao dos valores\n");
  ext_user->x = 4;
  ext_user->y = 6;
  ext_user->z = 8.5;
  return 0;
  }

int update_user( USER *ext_user )
  {
  if(ext_user == NULL)
    {
    free(ext_user);
    return -1;
    } 
    
  printf("Altera valores\n");
  ext_user->x *= 2;
  ext_user->y *= 4;
  ext_user->z *= 6;
  return 0;
  }

void
print_user( USER *ext_user )
  {
  if(ext_user == NULL)
    {
    free(ext_user); 
    return;
    } 
    
  printf
    (
    "Valor para X:: %d\n"
    "Valor para Y:: %d\n"
    "Valor para Z:: %f\n",
    ext_user->x,
    ext_user->y,
    ext_user->z
    );
  }

int 
main( void )
  {
  USER   stt_user = {0,0,0.0f}; // Valores presetados 
  USER*  ptr_user = (USER *) malloc(sizeof(USER)); // Stdlib - malloc :: Valores não presetados.
  
  /*  Repara no [ & ], passagem da posicao de memoria do elemento */
  printf("Struct Estatica \/\n");
  insert_user(&stt_user);
  print_user( &stt_user);
  update_user(&stt_user);
  print_user( &stt_user);
  
  /*  Esta mais na questao da forma como foi passado o parametro */
  printf("\n\nStruct Alocada Dinamicamente \/\n");
  insert_user(ptr_user); 
  print_user( ptr_user);
  update_user(ptr_user);
  print_user( ptr_user);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Observacao, tem um pequeno erro nos scapes de \ /  do printf, mas acredito que não afetar na compilação só vai dar warning.

Comment: era mesmo porblema com passar o Id ao inves da posição no array , muito obrigado

Comment: Opa, que bacana que deu certo.